# RSReportDesigner.config missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

RSReportDesigner.config is missing in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies.
I need to add custom data source extension to it.

I have installed by far:
1) visual studio 2012.
2) SQL CLR types. 
3) MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME
4) Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 
5) SQL server express 2012.

Any ideas why i have the file missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled visual studio and bids and it helped